# Оптимизация /Ob,разрешающая __forceinline подстановку не работает

Tags: c, visual-studio, оптимизация

Столкнулся с проблемой в Visual Studio.[image: /Ob1]
Оптимизация выдает ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать так,чтобы оптимизация срабатывала и разрешала вставку *forceinline*

Comment: Во-первых, с чего вы взяли, что прямо туда в графу "Оптимизация" можно руками писать `/Ob1`? Во-вторых, вставку `__forceinline` не надо "настраивать". Вставка `__forceinline` делается всегда, когда это не запрещено в настройках и объективно возможно. Никаких `/Ob1` для этого трогать не надо.

Comment: @AnT,но тут так написано https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/47238hez.aspx

Comment: И где вы там прочитали, что `/Ob1` можно вписывать руками прямо в графу "Оптимизация"? Внизу в разделе ""Установка данного параметра компилятора в среде разработки Visual Studio"" ясно написано:  "Измените свойство **Подстановка встраиваемой функции.**"

Comment: @AnT,это в свойствах проекта, в графе с/с++ , оптимизации "включить подставляемые функции"?В этой графе можно только /Oi выставить...Нашёл

Comment: Это глюк перевода. Во второй строке "подставляемые" значит "inilne". В третье строке "подставляемые" значит "intrinsic". Это совершенно разные вещи. В третье строке должно было быть написано "встроенные", а не "подставляемые". Вам же нужна именно вторая строка: "Развертывание подставляемых функций".